# How to compare 2 list of rows values and replace values by rows of a third list

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I would like to compare 2 list : `LISTE_PROJ` and `INFOS_PROJETS` and when I found a row on `LISTE_PROJ` === to a row in `INFOS_PROJETS`, replace all the row into the first list by the  row of a third list called `INFOS_PROJETSPOURCENTS`.

here is how the values look like in a `Logger.log()` :

```
  var LISTE_PROJ = [['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, true],
                    ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, true],
                    ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, true],
                    ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, false]]
```

```
var INFOS_PROJETS = [['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, true],
                        ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, true]]
```

```
var INFOS_PROJETSPOURCENTS = [[0.15,'NONE', 0.35,'NONE', 0.4, 0.1],
                                  [0.15,'NONE', 0.35,'NONE', 0.5,'NONE']]
```

So my new list of data will look like that on a `Logger.log(NEW_LISTE_PROJ)` :

```
var NEW_LISTE_PROJ = [
['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, true],
[0.15,NONE, 0.35,NONE, 0.4, 0.1],
[0.15,NONE, 0.35,NONE, 0.5, ],
['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, false]
]
```

Based on different post that I found on stackoverflow, I have created this code :

```
function REPART() {


  var LISTE_PROJ = [['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, true],
                    ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, true],
                    ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, true],
                    ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, false]]

  
  
  var INFOS_PROJETS = [['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, true],
                        ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, true]]
  

  var INFOS_PROJETSPOURCENTS = [[0.15,'NONE', 0.35,'NONE', 0.4, 0.1],
                                  [0.15,'NONE', 0.35,'NONE', 0.5, ]]
  
for (z = 0; z < LISTE_PROJ.length; z++) {
    for (j = 0; j < INFOS_PROJETS.length; j++) {
      if (LISTE_PROJ[z][0] === INFOS_PROJETS[j][0]) {
        for (k = 0; k < INFOS_PROJETSPOURCENTS.length; k++) {

         Logger.log('OK')
         //TESTsheet.getRange(i + 5,LISTE_PROJ[z]).setValue(INFOS_PROJETSPOURCENTS[k][(INFOS_PROJETSPOURCENTS[k]+15)])


        }
      }
    } 
  }
```

But It don't really works for different reason.

1/ I don't compare all the column of the row, but only the first column `[0]` (anyway to change that easely ? I have test `[0,1,2,3,4]` and it don't works).

2/ Even if I compare only 4 row, the `Logger.log()` return 6 time `OK` (maybe it compare `LISTE_PROJ` to `INFOS_PROJETS` and the also `INFOS_PROJETS` to `LISTE_PROJ` which made 4 OK + 2 OK ?).

3/ I would like to get the result in a var `NEW_LISTE_PROJ` to continue to work on it.

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through `lArr` to [find the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of the matching `row` in `iArr` and if found, use the found index to get the corresponding `iArr2` element, else return the same row(`lRow`)

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const lArr = [
  ['Scénographie', true, true, true, true, true],
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, true],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, true],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, false],
];

const iArr = [
  ['Plan tactile', false, false, false, false, true],
  ['Maquette tactile bâtiment', false, false, false, false, true],
];

const iArr2 = [
  [0.15, 'NONE', 0.35, 'NONE', 0.4, 0.1],
  [0.15, 'NONE', 0.35, 'NONE', 0.5, 'NONE'],
];

const out = lArr.map(
  (lRow) =>
    iArr2[iArr.findIndex((iRow) => iRow.every((el, i) => el === lRow[i]))] ?? lRow
);

console.log(out);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I absolutely don't understand what you did... bt it works ! Can I ask you just an edit... if there is no == in the list, I would like the value to be replace by ['NONE','NONE','NONE','NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE'], it will be perfect... thanks !

Comment: @emilianoSala Look into mdn for all the array methods used.

Comment: what is mdn ? do you have a link to give ?

Comment: @emilianoSala Mozilla Developer Network. Some links are in my answer. Just change `?? lRow` to `?? ['NONE','NONE','NONE','NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE']`