# trouble while comparating 2 list of rows values and replace values

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Here is a code I create to try to compare 2 list of rows values and replace values by rows of a third list. But it didn't produce the result I was expecting !

```js
//liste compléte
const lArr = [ 
    ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV','0','0','0','0'],
    ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV','0','0','0','0'],
    ['ARROMANCHES','0','0','0','0'],
    ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM','0','0','0','0'],
    ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM','0','0','0','0'],
    ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM','0','0','0','0'],
    ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM','0','0','0','0'],
    ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM','0','0','0','0'],
    ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ','0','0','0','0'],
    ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ','0','0','0','0']
  ];
//liste des config autorisées
const iArr = [ 
    ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV','0','0','0','0'],
    ['ARROMANCHES','0','0','0','0'],
    ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ','0','0','0','0'],
  ];
//list des choses qui remplacent
const iArr2 = [ 
     ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV, 2D, "MAREIKE", 50, 33.0'],
     ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, SOLENN, 50, 23.5'],
     ['ARROMANCHES, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, NICOLAS, 50, 6.0'],
     ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM, FABRICATION, CAMILLE, 50, 6.0'],
     ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, ALEXANDRA, 50, 2.0'],
     ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, LOUISE, 50, 3.75'],
     ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM, 2D, JULIEN, 50, 31.5'],
     ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM, 2D, MARTINA, 50, 4.0'],
     ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ, FABRICATION, ZELIE, 50, 4.0'],
     ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ, FABRICATION, CAMILLE, 50, 4.5']
     ];

const out = lArr.map(
  (lRow) =>
iArr2[iArr.findIndex((iRow) => iRow.every((el, i) => el === lRow[i]))] ?? ['NONE','NONE','NONE','NONE', 'NONE']
);

console.log(out);
```

so what I want as a result in `console.log(out);` would have been :

```
[ 
         ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV, 2D, "MAREIKE", 50, 33.0'],
         ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, SOLENN, 50, 23.5'],
         ['ARROMANCHES, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, NICOLAS, 50, 6.0'],
         ['NONE','NONE','NONE','NONE', 'NONE'],
         ['NONE','NONE','NONE','NONE', 'NONE'],
         ['NONE','NONE','NONE','NONE', 'NONE'],
         ['NONE','NONE','NONE','NONE', 'NONE'],
         ['NONE','NONE','NONE','NONE', 'NONE'],
         ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ, FABRICATION, ZELIE, 50, 4.0'],
         ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ, FABRICATION, CAMILLE, 50, 4.5']
         ]
```

and it's definitly not the case, as the code seems to kind of jump lines and overwrite some stuff...

I have based my code on this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77103637/how-to-compare-2-list-of-rows-values-and-replace-values-by-rows-of-a-third-list), but I haven't been able to understand anything to it, what I know is that he is perfectly working for the case of the other subject, and not for this particular case here.

I have also try to catch some info on this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), but even if it allowed me to understand some stuff, it didn't really help me to find a solution...

I guess that this code might be able to work with small modification, but if you come with a total different proposition that do the job I will appreciate it to !

thanks for your help !

Comment: ``["1", "2"]`` is a array with  two elements- 1 and 2. `['1,2']` is a array with 1 element- a string '1,2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
//liste compléte
const lArr = [
  ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['ARROMANCHES', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ', '0', '0', '0', '0']
];
//liste des config autorisées
const iArr = [
  ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['ARROMANCHES', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
  ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
];
//list des choses qui remplacent
const iArr2 = [
  ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV, 2D, "MAREIKE", 50, 33.0'],
  ['ALPINES MUSEUM DAV, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, SOLENN, 50, 23.5'],
  ['ARROMANCHES, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, NICOLAS, 50, 6.0'],
  ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM, FABRICATION, CAMILLE, 50, 6.0'],
  ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, ALEXANDRA, 50, 2.0'],
  ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, LOUISE, 50, 3.75'],
  ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM, 2D, JULIEN, 50, 31.5'],
  ['BELVEDERE MUSEUM, 2D, MARTINA, 50, 4.0'],
  ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ, FABRICATION, ZELIE, 50, 4.0'],
  ['BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ, FABRICATION, CAMILLE, 50, 4.5']
];

const out = lArr.map((r, i) => iArr.some(rr => rr.join("") == r.join("")) ? iArr2[i] : ['NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE']);

console.log(out);
```

- When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

```json
[
  ["ALPINES MUSEUM DAV, 2D, \"MAREIKE\", 50, 33.0"],
  ["ALPINES MUSEUM DAV, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, SOLENN, 50, 23.5"],
  ["ARROMANCHES, PROJECT MANAGEMENT, NICOLAS, 50, 6.0"],
  ["NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE"],
  ["NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE"],
  ["NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE"],
  ["NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE"],
  ["NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE","NONE"],
  ["BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ, FABRICATION, ZELIE, 50, 4.0"],
  ["BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ, FABRICATION, CAMILLE, 50, 4.5"]
]
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)